# PostgreSQL service unable to stop/start/restart

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, centos6

I am on CentOS 6.5 running PostGreSQL 9.3 and when I run the command `service postgresql-9.3 stop` I get the [  OK  ] as if it has stopped but the service is either still running or starts automatically when it is stopped because I can run the `service postgresql-9.3 stop` over and over again and always get the [  OK  ] as if it has been stopped.  Trying to start or restart gives the [FAILED] message.  How can I stop this?  I get an error that says `FATAL:  could not create any TCP/IP sockets` when I try to run `rake db:setup` for my rails project.  There is no socket file in the /tmp directory for PrestGreSQL but it seems like PG thinks there is.  I had the idea to uninstall postgres and do a fresh install but I need to stop the service in order for it to work.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Run: pgrep postgres should list a bunch of PIDs. Is it running? Is your rails database config correct?

Comment: Did you use `sudo` or run the command as root - `sudo service ...` ?

Comment: @CraigRinger I'm running as root.

Comment: @AndrewWei There are no results with that command.  I believe my database config is good but I'll review it.  Thanks.

Comment: Next step then is to look at the PostgreSQL server error logs. See if there's anything informative there. Also look at the main system logs (/var/log/messages, /var/log/daemon, etc).

Answer (score 0):

Check the stauts of the service
    service postgresql-9.1 status

If service already stopped, find any zombie process and kill
    ps -ef | grep postgres

Comment: when I checked the status the result is 'postgresql-9.3 stopped'.  the command `ps -ef | grep postgres` outputs this:

"root     12535 12432  0 10:59 pts/1    00:00:00 grep postgres".  

which doesn't seem to be anything but the command I had just run.  The behavior is still happening.  I am interested in the zombie process possibility which sounds like it would explain my problem.