# Unable to restart the Postgres server and can not kill the process

Tags: centos, postgresql-9.3

Due to a sudden power cut PostGreSQL 9.3 database server (CentOS) was down , I tried to start/stop/restart postgres server getting  this error:

```
[root@aca80123 ~]# service postgresql-9.3 restart 

    Restarting PostgreSQL 9.3: 
    pg_ctl: PID file "/opt/PostgreSQL/9.3/data/postmaster.pid" does not exist
    Is server running?
    starting server anyway
    waiting for server to start........ stopped waiting
    pg_ctl: could not start server
    Examine the log output.
    PostgreSQL 9.3 did not start in a timely fashion, please see /opt/PostgreSQL/9.3/data/pg_log/startup.log for details
```

Below messages are in the startup.log file

```
2016-03-01 23:24:18 IST LOG:  redirecting log output to logging collector process
2016-03-01 23:24:18 IST HINT:  Future log output will appear in directory "pg_log".
```

I found the stackOverflow questions  but there are no solutions.
[postgresql-service-unable-to-stop-start-restart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22822893/postgresql-service-unable-to-stop-start-restart)
[unable-to-restart-postgresql-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31460644/unable-to-restart-postgresql-server)

Answer (score 1):

If PID file does not exists.Try to check all the idle sessions that are using postgresql database.

```
ps -ef|grep postgres
```

Kill all the sessions using postgresql.
Check the status of the database

```
pg_ctl status
pg_ctl: no server running
```

After starting the server:

```
pg_ctl start
server starting
**postgres@server_name:~$ 2016-03-02 11:44:10 IST    LOG:  redirecting log output to logging collector process
2016-03-02 11:44:10 IST    HINT:  Future log output will appear in directory "pg_log".
```

Check for the status

```
pg_ctl status

pg_ctl: server is running (PID: 51615)
/opt/postgres/9.3/bin/postgres
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem some time ago with the postmaster.pid. For me the problem was that it was not deleted and thus it could not restart. For you it seems that the postmaster.pid does not exists and that it expects to be there.

Did you check in "/opt/PostgreSQL/9.3/data/" if the postmaster.pid really isnt there? Back then I found out it was a file that protects you from doing multiple calls on the same table. So maybe another database is working on the same tables or something like that? Hope that answer can give you some direction.

Good luck.

Comment: Inside the "/opt/PostgreSQL/9.3/data/" there are no postmaster.pid file.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to search for postgres pid in

```
    ps aux
```

and when you find it you can kill it using

```
    kill -9 postgresPID
```

I don't know if this help you, but it worked for me.

Comment: Normally I am using above command. its working but this time above commands did not work.

Answer (score 0):

In the file postgres.conf uncomment the attributes related to logging.

```
# These are only used if logging_collector is on:
log_directory = 'log'           # directory where log files are written,
                    # can be absolute or relative to PGDATA
log_filename = 'postgresql-%Y-%m-%d_%H%M%S.log' # log file name pattern,
                    # can include strftime() escapes
```

This will generate a log file mentioning the error in the folder mentioned for 'log_directory' attribute.

In my case, there was a process running on the same port(5432).
Killing it solved the issue for me.